# Optimize a backend rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, activerecord, optimization, rubygems

I have a rails app which serves as a backend for Bootstrap based frontend. My application is fully Rest based. Which tools can I use to find the unused joins or queries from database in code? Also, any tools/gems that can help in finding the code that can be refactored?

There are gems like Bullet or Rack-mini-profiler that work if Rails app is used to render view also. But how do I use gems like those to optimize and tune my queries and code if only way to get a response is from rest client?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the configuration of Bullet, I believe by default Bullet logs all optimizable queries in `(Rails.root/log/bullet.log)`, I guess the others have similar configurations/logs.

You could setup bullet for your test environment, since if you're shooting for a good coverage you'd most likely be testing all the AR methods in the first place.

Additional enhancers are New Relic and tools like Rubocop for some best practice.

You should [check this out as well](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/top-8-tools-for-ruby-on-rails-code-optimization-and-cleanup).